# PHP array search for file type and see if file exist

Tags: php, arrays, search

```
<?php
$rn = $_GET['rn'];

$file_exts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png");
$upload_exts = end(explode(".", $rn));

#$images/$rn

if (in_array($upload_exts, $file_exts)) {

  #if (in_array(file_exists($haystack), $needle) {
  if (array_search($upload_exts, $file_exts/*file_exists("c:/xampp\htdocs\php/images/" .*/)) {
     $str_img = str_replace(' ', '_', $rn);
  } else {
     $str_img = 'thumb.png';
  }
}

echo $str_img;
?>
```

Okay so I have this code, but I can't get the result I'm looking for.
I want to see if a file exist, using `array_*` and other functions like `file_exists`.
What my problem is, when I want to add a new file type, I will just type it in the `array` field, and it will search for it, if an image/file was found, the file name + file type will be printed out 
e.g `google-img.jpg`, else it whould print `thumb.png`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use file_exists with dirname(__ FILE __):

```
$rn = $_GET['rn'];
$file_exts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png");
$upload_exts = end(explode(".", $rn));

function exists( $file ) {
$file_exts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png");
$upload_exts = end(explode(".", $file));
 if( in_array($upload_exts, $file_exts) && file_exists( dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . $file ) )
  return $file;
 foreach($file_exts as $a)
 if( file_exists( dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . $file . '.' . $a) )
  return $file.'.'.$a;
 return false;
 }
 if( exists($_GET['rn']) )
   $str_img = str_replace(" ", "_", exists($_GET['rn']));
 else
   $str_img = 'thumb.png';
echo $str_img;
```

Comment: Not quite what I meant...
If the file exist, the thumb.png will not be printed as it does now. 
I have an image named 01.jpg, and when I type in 01 in the url, it prints out "Extension is invalid". But what I mean was, if the image does not exist, then the thumb.png will be printed

Comment: file_Exists just will work if you add the extension, else you have to try with multiple the 3 extensions. I've edited the comment. Does it work now?

Comment: your function `exists` returns `true` or `false` or `filename` ??? `$str_img = str_replace(" ", "_", exists($_GET['rn']));` can result in `$str_img = str_replace(" ", "_", true);` there is no function `str_replace` with argument `true` !

Comment: re-edited, now it returns the filename. It will return the filename if file exists, and will return false if not.

Comment: you should use 2 functions **A** : look for If extension exists `$file_exts` . **B** : look for if file exists . At the moment you test for extension and return `$file` but did not test if `$file` exists. Please do not let us step by step correct your code. Test it !

Comment: Now let's come to the next mistake : What is the difference between : `return $file;` and `return $file.'.'.$a;` eg `image01.jpg` and `image01.jpg.jpg` !

Comment: I've edited it again, sorry. Now it checks if $file extension is allowed and also checks if file exists directly. If not, it will use the foreach and the foreach just tries with the available extensions.

Comment: do you have the other illogical parts already found in your code ?

Comment: the difference between `image01.jpg` and `image01.jpg.jpg` :-)

Comment: But... it just checks the last part, I'm trying with lol.png.png and it fails, lol.png and runs ok. It just checks that ".jpg" be the end and file to exist... I'm not getting you... :(

Comment: you return a) `$file` and 3 lines later b) `$file.'.'.$a;` results in a) `image01.jpg` or b) `image01.jpg.jpg` !

Comment: Did you try the code? In my localhost it works for lol.png and lol.png.png because it is assumed that return will end the code execution

Comment: assume $file comes in with value `image01.jpg` It only works this part `if( in_array($upload_exts, $file_exts) && file_exists( dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . $file ) )
  return $file;` with `file_exists(image01.jpg`) ||| in your foreach loop you are searching for **$file + . + $file_exts** . Why you are searching for `image01.jpg.jpg` that make no sense.

Comment: You mean, if $file is "image01.jpg" and it doesn't exist, code shouldn't check for image01.jpg.jpg, right? :P

Comment: why should the code do that? Then there is an open end. Search for image01.jpg.jpg.jpg etc. What you want to achieve, you want to see whether `image01.png` or `image01.jpeg` exists that makes sense. That's why you go through all the file extensions.